# Need to source bash_profile each time

Tags: linux, bash, tomcat

I have get a server space that runs linux. A user is created for me. I have a bash_profile in my home directory and I set environment variables for JAVA_HOME and JAVA.

When I access server through [putty](http://www.putty.org/) I have to source the bash_profile each time I log. Is that an error?

Because I cannot access the tomcat server home page via IP address:portNo. Does that relate to above problem.

Comment: It's `.bash_profile`, with a period.

Comment: yes. Sorry, I have misspelled in question only. It's correct on server.

Comment: Are you sure you are starting Bash and not some alternative shell (tcsh, zsh, …)? You can e.g. `grep` for your username in `/etc/passwd` to see your settings.